# How can I move one figure up to align with another figure?

Tags: graphics, align

I am trying to add 4 photos of different heights to my document but they do not align! I cannot move up the ones shown with red in the photo, so they align with the rest (page 1 and page 3 in the code). How can I fix that?

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth,scale=0.6,page=1]{Survey 1.pdf}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth,scale=0.6,page=3]{Survey 1.pdf}\hfill\\[\smallskipamount]%
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth,scale=0.6,page=2]{Survey 1.pdf}\hfill% 
\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth,scale=0.6,page=4]{Survey 1.pdf}
\caption{Some images}\label{fig:foobar}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please do tell us which document class you employ.

Answer (score 3):

It is easier for us to help if you provide a MWE (minimal working example) that we can compile directly. Images can be replaced with `example-image-a`.

One solution to place images is to use `\raisebox`, or `adjustbox` that provides a `valign` parameter:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % provide the key valign, but I don't find it really precise compared to raisebox, not sure why
\begin{document}

Compare:\\ \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}

With:\\

\includegraphics[valign=t,width=3cm]{example-image-a}\includegraphics[valign=t,width=5cm]{example-image-a}

Or:\\

\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[valign=t,width=3cm]{example-image-a}}\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[valign=t,width=5cm]{example-image-a}}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One more example with use of `adjustbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % it loads graphicx package too

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=.48\textwidth}  % all images have equal width
\includegraphics[height=33mm,           % in real document remove this option 
                 valign=T]{example-image-a}\hfill%
\includegraphics[height=44mm,           % in real document remove this option
                 valign=T]{example-image-b}

\medskip
\includegraphics[height=33mm,           % in real document remove this option
                 valign=T]{example-image-a}\hfill%
\includegraphics[height=55mm,           % in reall document remove this option
                 valign=T]{example-image-b}
    \caption{Some images}
    \label{fig:foobar}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Observe that for `valign` keys are used `T` option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

Does the following setup work for you? (Note that I've gotten rid of the `scale=0.6` option in all cases.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htpb]
\includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth,page=1]{Survey 1.pdf}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth,page=3]{Survey 1.pdf}

\medskip
\includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth,page=2]{Survey 1.pdf}\hfill% 
\includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth,page=4]{Survey 1.pdf}
\caption{Some images}\label{fig:foobar}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```